# How can I make the touch screen work properly on portrait left in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: xorg, touchscreen

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 on some old hardware that's attached to a 32 inch digital signage touch screen. In landscape orientation the touch functionality works flawlessly the issue is, the 32 inch screen is mounted vertically and must stay that way.

When I set the display orientation to portrait left the touch works, but the points are not mapped properly. For example, if I touch the *Show Applications* icon it opens Firefox.

[image: Picture of screen]

Looking through Google I found a calibration tool, but that tool didn't work with xwayland. I turned off xwayland and forced xorg on boot, but after running the calibration and copying the snippet to the only config file I could find, I could no longer boot.

Now I am on a fresh install of Ubuntu and don't know where to start.

Comment: I have a similar problem, only mine is with an Asus Zenbook Q302LA 2-in-1 laptop. My rotation doesn't work correctly and has a bad habit of being oriented to the left when I am using my laptop like a laptop instead of a tablet. I am actually using SDDM instead of GDM3, because SDDM seems to have more appropiate drivers installed for my touchscreen, oddly enough.